# what does "stretching into" mean?

Tags: meaning

This is a quote from the Wikipedia page for [Freddie Mercury](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freddie_Mercury).

> [Freddie Mercury] did a commendable job of stretching into uncharted territory.

Could someone tell me what does "stretching into" mean?

Comment: You can understand the figurative use of "stretch into new territory" here as meaning "trying things that had not been done before". He is compared to an explorer entering virgin land and if we want to keep the metaphor we could replace stretching by *going* or *entering*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dictionary definition of stretching: To cause to extend from one place to another or across a given space. This, however, is not what it means in this sentence. This word is used in this sentence as somewhat a metaphor. Basically, it comes from the idea that stretching something makes it more tense and uses more energy to stretch it out further. The sentence is saying that Freddy Mercury put extra effort into getting into uncharted territory. So, in short, [Freddie Mercury] did a commendable job of (putting extra effort into reaching) uncharted territory.